# Ruby on Rails has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starting with Ruby on Rails and I am having a few difficulties.

To give a bit of context what I am trying to do is an app where users can create accounts, each account has one channel and each channel has an amount of videos.

Also there is a timelines which every video can add videos to. So timelines also has many videos.

By now I have the following models:

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :videos
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :channel
  has_many :timelines
end

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel
end

class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :videos
end
```

How can I build an relation where a video can belong to channel and at the same time belong to timeline?

I think the best way to do it is to have a new table with name like **timelinerelation** with fields **ID_TIMELINE**, **ID_VIDEO** and for instance for timeline one I have videos 2,3,4 and for timeline 2 I have videos 3,4,5.

So the table would have:

```
1 2;
1 3;
1 4;
2 3;
2 4;
2 5;
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to do this in ruby on rails.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @AbM so basicly I should generate a new scaffold that will relate them both? I was thinking about that, but I was not sure. Then I write the migration similar to the one on "The corresponding migration might look like this:" and then rake db:migrate ?

Comment: @AbM ha ok great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the example you provided, I see that a video can belong to multiple timelines. If so, you need to set up a many to many relationship as outline [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

In your case, you can create a join model, say `TimelineRelation` by running:

`rails g model TimelineRelation timeline:references video:references`

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :channel
  has_many :timeline_relations
  has_many :timelines, through: timeline_relations
end

class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :timeline_relations
  has_many :videos, through: timeline_relations
end

class TimelineRelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timeline
  belongs_to :video
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need extra table. Simply add field timeline_id to video model and add another belongs_to relation

Comment: I believe what @heisenberg is looking for is a many to many relationship. In the example he gave, Video 3 belongs to both Timeline 1 and Timeline 2